Mailing data reports over time
I'd like to be able to show some data to our board of trustees about the impact of our mailings - e.g. subscription, open, click-through rates over the last year.
I don't want to display this in CiviCRM itself, but not sure if its possible to get the data out.
Any tips would be really appreciated.
